What tag should be used to for questions about "green mining" or the overall earth impact of mining?
I'd like to add a tag to questions that 

Quantify the electrical cost of mining
Connect the dots between mining and the impact on the earth's resources

What tag is most appropriate for this?
The end result is that we can improve searching and reduce redundancies when dealing with this type of question.

How about the [tag:electricity] tag?

How about an [Ecology] tag?
